# org.jboss.logging.Logger instead of class names printed in log depending on runtime environment

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, slf4j

I have a big application running on JBoss 5.1 and using log4j via slf4j. When I test in a local docker container I can see the usual package.class name in the log:

```
03 Dec 15 09:45:39, DEBUG  my.fancy.app.filters.TicketValidationFilter:doFilter:30 Ticket was verified with data: uniqueID=gfd, idnumber=sdf, mid=11246986.
03 Dec 15 09:45:39, DEBUG  my.fancy.app.MyServlet:doGet:30 Request for secret data with uniqueId=gfd
03 Dec 15 09:45:39, WARN   my.fancy.app.MyServlet:doGet:36 Could not retrieve SecretData with uniqueId=gfd
```

However when I deploy the same code to the dev environment (which might not be as clean...) I get:

```
03 dec 15 10:45:22, DEBUG  org.jboss.logging.Logger:debug:228 Ticket was verified with data: uniqueID=sdg, idnumber=sdf, mid=11738149.
03 dec 15 10:45:22, DEBUG  org.jboss.logging.Logger:debug:228 Request for secret data with uniqueId=sdg
03 dec 15 10:45:22, WARN   org.jboss.logging.Logger:warn:352 Could not retrieve SecretData with uniqueId=sdg
```

I have compared the jboss-log4j.xml in both environments and they are identical. I have also checked the startup flags to see if the logging provider is set, but it is in neither of those environments.

Where should I look next?

**Update**

I should also mention that previously we've been using log4j directly and so we still have direct log4j imports and instantiations scattered here and there. The strange thing is then that those entries which were logged with log4j show correctly in all environments, whereas those with slf4j only in some. This should be a clue that slf4j is not really configured correctly in the offending environments. The question is where should I look to fix it?

**Update 2**

This is the appender configuration:

`<appender name="MYAPP_FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/myapp.log" />
      <param name="Append" value="true" />
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyy HH:mm:ss}, %-6p %C:%M:%L %m %n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>`

The logger declartation:

`import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName());
...
        log.debug("Request for secret data with uniqueId={}", secretDataVO.getUniqueId());
...
}`

In the pom.xml I have:

`<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`

The dependency on log4j is there because in other places in the application code we still use log4j directly. slf4j-log4j12 is marked as provided because it is loaded by another artifact in the same jboss instance.

**Update 3**

There is an error shown when starting jboss:

`2015-12-07 16:16:50,127 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR A "org.jboss.logging.appender.FileAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
2015-12-07 16:16:50,127 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by
2015-12-07 16:16:50,127 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR [BaseClassLoader@14a33aa{vfszip:/my-jboss-root/jboss/server/default/deploy/fancyApp.ear/fancyApp-web.war/}] whereas object of type
2015-12-07 16:16:50,127 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR "org.jboss.logging.appender.FileAppender" was loaded by [org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@15b0afd].
2015-12-07 16:16:50,127 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "FILE".`

Where fancyApp-web.war is the one loading slf4j-log4j12. I saw this error before, but didn't mention it as it appears both in the local (docker) and in the dev environments (even in prod for that matter...)

Comment: Please attach your slf4j configuration file (mainly for log format) and show how you declare your loggers. Also you should recheck your application dependencies so that they include needed files for slf4j and log4j. Are you using legacy log4j?

Comment: @Taavi: See the added information. I don't know what you mean by "legacy" log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServlet.class)` and as noteded here: http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html#getLogger%28java.lang.Class%29

> In case the the clazz parameter differs from the name of the caller as
>   computed internally by SLF4J, a logger name mismatch warning will be
>   printed but only if the slf4j.detectLoggerNameMismatch system property
>   is set to true. By default, this property is not set and no warnings
>   will be printed even in case of a logger name mismatch.

Also set `debug="true"` in your log4j.xml and observe log4j initialization.

Comment: Why should that change anything? Do you mean that I should look if when debug is enabled some specific error should appear in the log?

Comment: Yes you should check how your logging environment is being setup, sorry for not clearly pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Set debugger for production environment true and also in the config file.

Comment: You mean to get debug logging? What should I look for? WHich config file are you talking about?

Comment: JBoss_HOME\server\default\conf\jboss-log4j.xml

Comment: Also this might give you some insights : https://community.jboss.org/thread/200818?tstart=0